# Can't import flutter release on google play

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, release

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNhRU.png)

I can't import import the release that I build to google play store

Answer (score 0):

You might selecting **debug** in build variants. if yes, then select **release** and proceed.

[image]